# How did Darren Cross switch sides so easily?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

In the 2023 movie, *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, this conversation takes place between Cassie (Scott's daughter) and Darren who is in M.O.D.O.K. suit, after a brief fight near the end of the movie:

> **Cassie**: Darren, just stop trying to be whatever this is.
>
> **Darren**: I don’t know what to be. Tell me what to be.
>
> **Cassie**: I don’t know. Just don’t be a dick.
>
> **Darren**: It’s too late. Look at me. I’m such a dick.
>
> **Cassie**: It’s never too late to stop being a dick.

It seems Darren really wants to be a good person. But why?!

Later Darren sacrificed his life to help the protagonists defeat Kang the Conquerer.

When he was dying this conversation took place:

> **Scott**: Darren. Are you okay?
>
> **Darren**: (coughs) Probably not.
>
> **Hope**: (surprised) Darren?
>
> **Darren**: Hi, Hope. You changed your hair.
>
> **Hope**: What the hell happened?
>
> **Scott**: Yeah. No, it’s… It’s a whole thing. I’ll tell you later.
>
> **Scott**: (to Darren) That was… I… I don’t know what to say.
>
> **Darren**: (holding Scott's cheek) Thanks, Scott. **You always were a brother to me**.
>
> **Scott**: I was? (a few moments later) I was.
>
> **Darren**: (coughs and exhales sharply) And at least I died an Avenger.
>
> **Scott**: Yeah. You did. Yeah. No, it’s… You’re in.
>
> Darren dies.

How did Darren call Scott his always-brother? Darren was a great enemy of Scott in *Ant-Man* (2015 film) and Scott hated him so much in that film. Darren even kidnapped Cassie in that film.

And in this new film Darren even tried to kill Hank Pym who was his old mentor.

What was wrong with Darren in the near end? He wasn't himself.

How did Cassie convince him to turn good just by telling him two sentences? If it was that easy he would turn good in *Ant-Man*.

Comment: A little time in the Quantum Realm would cause anyone to rethink their life goals. Well, except Kang.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why he thinks Scott always was a brother to him. While clearly it's not true from both persons' perspective.

Comment: @EtackSxchange Scott clearly doesn't agree with the "You were always a brother to me" line, he just goes along with it rather than spend Darren's last moments arguing with him.

Comment: @PrincessAda I agree with you. The question is why Darren thinks that way.

Comment: @EtackSxchange, Scott and Darren both had Hank Pym as a mentor. It could be said that makes them sort of brothers (in a sort of competitive, love-hate way).